# Empty ClassName

Tags: reactjs

I have example:

```
var myClass = '';
if (this.state.foo) myClass = 'active';
return (
   <div className={myClass}></div>
)
```

Or inside `return`:

```
return (
   <div className={this.state.foo ? 'active' : '' }></div>
)
```

If `this.state.foo` is `false` in browser my code will look:

```
<div class></div>
```

Is it possible do not add `class` attribute if it's empty?

Comment: If you read the tag description, you will note that [tag:jsx] is not the right tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could probably do

```
var props = {};
if (this.state.foo) {
  props.myClass = 'active';
}
return (
   <div {...props}></div>
);
```

Comment: Thank you! It's not wrong, just for improve my skills in JSX

Answer (score 16):

You can return undefined instead of the empty string:

```
return (
   <div className={this.state.foo ? 'active' : undefined }></div>
)
```

Comment: this still render an empty class for me

Comment: @Stephen Still works for me with the latest version. What's your code?

Comment: update: should be undefined not null

Comment: @thinklinux Thanks for the heads up, I've updated my answer.